# Как копировать текст из Windows.Forms.Label в буфер по клику?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net

Как копировать текст из Windows.Forms.Label в буфер по клику?

Comment: люди ну хоть немного научитесь юзать гугл....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Clipboard.SetText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/tbfb3z56(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Очищает буфер обмена, а затем добавляет указанные текстовые данные в формате, указанном TextDataFormat значения.

```
private void label_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label label = sender as Label;

    if (label != null)
    {
        Clipboard.SetText(label.Text, TextDataFormat.UnicodeText);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Сглупил с поисковым запросом.

```
Clipboard.SetText("...");
```